# Space between section name and tables

Tags: tables

I am producing some tables (with no texts) to send the results to my coauthors. I am using the table environment to get automated table numbers and to contain the footnotes within table borders (below is an MWE). With lots of tables, I am trying to put section names above each set of tables. The problem I am facing is that the first table, does not matter how small it is, is moving to the next page. So the entire page below the section name remains empty. I was wondering if there is an easy way to solve that.

Kind regards,
Syed

```
\singlespacing
\renewcommand{\mywide}{17cm}
\begin{table}[t]\centering
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\parbox{\mywide}{
\caption{DD estimate of school quality measures by gap with predicted property price, Aug09-Jan10}}
\begin{tabularx} {\mywide} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y @{}} \\
\midrule
Average score & estimate & SE &  p-val & Observations  \\
\midrule
Year 3, 2008 &     2.59&     5.39&     0.63&    1,047\\
Year 3, 2009 &     6.77&     5.10&     0.19&    1,050\\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\doublespacing
\normalsize
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your table floats away. In this case, the best strategy is to drop the `table` environment and use `\captionof{table}{}` instead of `\caption`. You need the `caption` package for this. However, there are some issues to improve here too!

Comment: Did you try using `[!ht]` for the placement?

Comment: You could replace the bunch of 19(!!!!) `Y` - type column specifiers with `*{19}Y` ;-)

Comment: Thanks. \captionof{table}{} or  !ht did not solve the problem. Column specifiers are working nicely.

Comment: Your table is too wide by far, `\centering` has no effect then.

Answer (score 3):

Not the real solution, but to show some possibilities. I've changed from `tabularx` to `tabular` however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\mywide}{17cm}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}

\begin{document}


\section{First}
\begingroup
\centering
\singlespacing
%\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} % What's this?
%\parbox{\mywide}{%
\captionof{table}[Short title]{DD estimate of school quality measures by gap with predicted property price, Aug09-Jan10}
%}%

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{Y}@{}} \\
\midrule
Average score & estimate & SE &  p-val & Observations  \\
\midrule
Year 3, 2008 &     2.59&     5.39&     0.63&    1,047\\
Year 3, 2009 &     6.77&     5.10&     0.19&    1,050\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
%\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer. I can run that too but whenever I include the same table with \include command, it does not work.

Comment: @Syedhasan: Of course not, since `\include` automatically uses a `\clearpage`, i.e. inserts a new page effectively and then the content of the file. Use `\input` instead of `\include`

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer. \input partially solved the problem.

Comment: @Syedhasan: Partially?

Comment: Ok, fully. But in my case, tables are large and i still need to use \vspace to keep section headers at the same page with tables.

Comment: @Syedhasan: Well, I can not answer stuff which isn't available to me. A table with 19 columns is most likely too large for the width at least.